# Vaadin 21 flow. NumberField width vs NumberField Input Field width

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

How to set different width (shorter) for input field in `NumberField` than label or helper for this field.

```java
NumberField numberField = new NumberField("Label");
numberField.setWidthFull(); // full width for the whole NumberField
// how to set width = 12rem for input field inside NumberField
// i try to 
numberField.getStyle().set("--input-field-width", "12rem");
//but its not working
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the width of the input inside the field?

Comment: If the problem is that the label has a long text and gets cut short, would styling the label to overflow work instead?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use CSS to theme the `part="input-field"`. In your frontend folder, under the directory
`/frontend/themes/[your-theme]/components/`
create the file `vaadin-number-field.css` if one doesn't exist already.

In that file, add this:

```
[part="input-field"] {
    width: 12rem;
}
```